# Как установить драйвер сетевого адаптера mcp55 v3 на centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, драйвер, repository, redhat

При установки centos 7 minimal я обнаружил что ось неопределяет сетевой адаптер, гугл сказали что драйвер исключены с ядра, я вроде нашел альтернативу, советуют установить с репозитория http://mirror.symnds.com/distributions/elrepo/elrepo/el7/x86_64/RPMS/

kmod-forcedeth-0.64-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64

но дальше не могу понять что как устанавливать, после виндовс сложновато.

можете привести команды как устанавливать, или может можно запихнуть дрова в дистрибьютив установки.

Comment: установить пакет из файла: `rpm -i файл.rpm`

Comment: А в kmod-forcedeth-0.64-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 же вроде много драйверов или я ошибаюсь, поставиться только к моей mcp55 v3 или станут все.

Comment: для того, чтобы дать вам **исчерпывающие** рекомендации, надо написать целую статью не на одну тысячу знаков. краткий же совет: купите какой-нибудь дешёвенький ethernet-адаптер.

Comment: @АлексейМоргун, это один драйвер на все устройства, совместимые с forthedeth.